# push array object to new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

I have the following data:

```
var data = [{
    County: "Cork",
    date: '1/1/2018',
    num: 100
}, {
    County: "Roscommon",
    date: '07/10/2017',
    num: 27
}];
var Counties = {};
for (County in data) {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        Counties[data[i].County] = data[i].County;
    }
}
```

This returns `{County: "Roscommon"}`

How can I get my code to return every County in the array object so that I end up with:

```
{County: "Cork"}
{County: "Roscommon"}
```

Comment: why the second loop , also you're always setting to same key , also you can't have array with duplicate key

Comment: I thought that was the best way to access the data. but if there is an alternative better way - that would be great!

Comment: you can just have array with numbered indices

Comment: It needs to be an object though as I need to map it elsewhere, i.e. bind it in an object

Comment: Rather than use array indices

Comment: ahhh ok didn't notice that  , checkout the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array#map function.

```
const countyArray = data.map(el => {el.County})
```

or

```
const counties = [];
for (let county of data) {
   counties.push({ County })
}
```

As an object:

```
const counties = {}; 

for (let element of data) { 
counties[element.County] = {County: element.County};
}
```

Comment: No, I need this: 
{
  { "County": "Cork"},
  {"County": "Roscommon"}
}

Comment: What I mean is, I need to obtain back an object rather than array. Does that make sense?

Comment: JS object looks like this:
`{name: value, name: value}`.

In that case you need to do this:

`const counties = {};
for (let element of data) {
   counties[element.County] = County;
}`

Comment: Could you type the full code please as I am not sure how to implement this. Thanks very much

Comment: var data = [{
    County: "Cork",
    date: '1/1/2018',
    num: 100
}, {
    County: "Roscommon",
    date: '07/10/2017',
    num: 27
}];

const counties = {};

for (let element of data) {
  counties[element.County] = {County: element.County};
}

console.log(counties)

Also, see this:
https://jsbin.com/wacibejuhe/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Super, thats what I was looking for!! Super stuff - Could you explain what you did please as I'm new to javascript

Comment: no problem, can you please check my answer as correct? you have a "check" icon under the down arrow next to my answer :)

I iterated over the array and mapped it to an object. Objects in JS have two notations, dot and brackets. basically, i created a property in an object named by the county name, and assigned an object to that property that holds that name too. you should really consider using an array for this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array#map`. You can iterate on your array using the `array#map` and in its callback function, you can use object destructuring syntax to get the `County` value and using the object short-hand notation create the object with `County` value.

```js
var data = [{ County: "Cork", date:'1/1/2018', num:100 },{ County: "Roscommon", date: '07/10/2017', num:27 }],
    counties = data.map(({County}) => ({County}));
console.log(counties);
```

Comment: Your answer could use some explanation alongside the code to explain what the code does.

Comment: Updated the answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this? an array with objects with only the county values?

```js
var data = [{
    County: "Cork",
    date:'1/1/2018',
    num:100
  },{
    County: "Roscommon",
    date: '07/10/2017',
    num:27
  }];
var Counties=data.map(function(a){return {County:a.County}});
console.log(Counties);
```

Or this, an array with just the county names?

```js
var data = [{
    County: "Cork",
    date:'1/1/2018',
    num:100
  },{
    County: "Roscommon",
    date: '07/10/2017',
    num:27
  }];
var Counties=data.map(function(a){return a.County});
console.log(Counties);
```

For simple data mapping in an array I suggest you delve deeper in the functionality of map, which makes it pretty easy to "clean up" data in arrays to pick and choose the tidbits you want in the format you want it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

If you need unique values you need a couple of extra steps

```js
var data = [{
    County: "Cork",
    date:'1/1/2018',
    num:100
  },{
    County: "Roscommon",
    date: '07/10/2017',
    num:27
  },
  {
    County: "Roscommon",
    date: '17/10/2017',
    num:34
  }
  ];
console.log("#nofilter");

var counties=data.map(function(a){
                        return a.County
                      });

console.log(counties);

console.log("as filtered array");

var counties=data.map(function(a){
                     return a.County;
                  })
                 .filter(function(value, index, self) { 
                    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
                 });
console.log(counties);

console.log("as filtered objects");

var counties=data.map(function(a){return a.County})
                 .filter(function(value, index, self) { 
                     return self.indexOf(value) === index;
                 })
                 .map(function(a) {
                    return {County: a}
                 });
                 
console.log(counties);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your code has some issues, let's annalye them:**

**Your approach:**

```
var Counties={};
for (County in data){
  for (var i=0;i<=1;i++){
     Counties["County"]=data[i].County;
  }
}
```

The keyword `in` isn't well used here, because that operator returns the index for every item in your Array `data`

```
for (County in data)
            ^
```

You don't need that inner `for-loop` because you can iterate over `data` array directly :-)

```
for (County in data){
   for (var i=0;i<=1;i++){ // Remove that line
   ^
```

As you state in your question, your desired output is an array of objects.  So you need to declare an Array.

```
var Counties={};
^
```

**Look this code snippet, it's cleaner and follow your logic:**

```js
var data = [{
  County: "Cork",
  date: '1/1/2018',
  num: 100
}, {
  County: "Roscommon",
  date: '07/10/2017',
  num: 27
}];
var array = [];

for (c in data) {
   array.push({"County": data[c].County});
}

console.log(array);
```

See?, your logic is working now!

**A short approach using `reduce` function will be:**

The `reduce` won't modify your original Object.

```js
var data = [{
    County: "Cork",
    date: '1/1/2018',
    num: 100
}, {
    County: "Roscommon",
    date: '07/10/2017',
    num: 27
}];

var counties = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  return [...a, ...[{"county": c.County}]]
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(JSON.stringify(counties));
```

See?, your original Obj wasn't modified and a new Array with the counties was created.

**Another short approach using `map` function will be:**

The `map` won't modify your original Object.

```js
var data = [{
    County: "Cork",
    date: '1/1/2018',
    num: 100
}, {
    County: "Roscommon",
    date: '07/10/2017',
    num: 27
}];

var counties = data.map((c) => ({"county": c.County}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(JSON.stringify(counties));
```

See?, your original Obj wasn't modified and a new Array with the counties was created.

## Resources

- [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`Spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best option is to map over the data array like so. 
`

```
var data = [{
    county: "Cork",
    date:'1/1/2018',
    num:100
  },{
    county: "Roscommon",
    date: '07/10/2017',
    num:27
  }];
var counties=[];
data.map(item => {
var county = {county: item.county};
counties.push(county);
});
```

`